# pandas multiindex index slice range

Tags: python, pandas, slice, multi-index

How can I subselect a pandas multi index easily for a range of values?

```
import pandas as pd
mini_df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})
mini_df['value'] = 2
mini_df['bar'] = 1
mini_df = mini_df.set_index(['bar', 'foo']).unstack()
mini_df['thing'] = -1
display(mini_df.head())
```

This:

```
mini_df[['thing', ('value', 2:5)]]
```

obviously fails to work.

I.e. how could I get an index slice that holds the column thing and the value columns 6-9?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gives the index slice that holds the column thing and the value columns 6-9:

`mini_df.loc[:, ('value', 6): ('thing', '')]`

```
    value          thing
foo     6  7  8  9
bar
1       2  2  2  2    -1
```